# How to convert a factor to numeric in a predefined order in R?

Tags: r

I have a factor column, with three values: "b", "c" and "free".

I did

```
df$new_col = as.numeric (df$factor_col)
```

But it will convert "b" to 1, "c" to 2 and "free" to 3.

But I want to convert "free" to 0, "b" to 2 and "c" to 5. How can I do it in R?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Please don't cross-post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007374/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-numeric-in-a-predefined-order-in-r)

Comment: Hi Stephan, I thought two websites are different. If it's not true, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or there is this code:

```
new_col = c(2,5,0)[as.numeric(factor_col)]
```

To elaborate, factors have "hidden" numerical values that go from 1 to the number of levels, assigned in alphabetical order (unless you used the ordered=TRUE argument when you declared the factor) as noted by the original question.  So I vectorized it by putting the values 2 (to recode level 1), 5 (to recode level 2) and 0 (to recode level 3).

In fact (this makes me a bit queasy) you can use coercion to get even smaller code:

```
new_col = c(2,5,0)[factor_col]
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer, or post it as a comment.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that but I had a feeling there might be an easier way, as there often is in R. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a default function for it, but you can do it manually:

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$factor_col=="b", 0, NA)
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$factor_col=="c", 2, df$new_col)
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$factor_col=="free", 5, df$new_col)
```

Or you can write a function that does it automatically:

```
factor.numeric <- function (factor, numbers) {
  num <- NA
  for (i in 1:length(levels(factor))) {
    num <- ifelse(factor==levels(factor)[i], numbers[i], num)
  }
  return(num)
}

factor.numeric(df$factor_col, c(0,2,5))
```

This should do it, provided the factors "b", "c", and "free" appear in that order in df$factor_col. You also need to source the function of course.